# I would like a button to trigger a link using jquery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a nav-pills element incorporated in my web page, which works perfectly.

The `li` tag will have a class of "active" if I'm on that tab and will only have a class of "test" if I'm not currently on that tab.

What I'm also trying to do is have an additional button for next and previous, so if I'm on the "Menu 1" tab and I hit next, I can go back to the "Introduction" tab. I attempted to have the button trigger the link but it doesn't work.

```html
<div class="card">
    <div class="header">                
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills center-pills">
                <li class="active" id="first" class="test"><a id="link1" class="test" href="#home">Introduction</a></li>
                <li class="test"><a href="#menu1" class="test">Menu 1</a></li>  
            </ul>
        </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="content">    
            <div class="tab-content">
                <!--first tab-->
                <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                    <h3>Introduction</h3>
                    <p>Random Text </p>
                    <button id="next-step" class="btn btn-basic">Next</button>
                </div>
                <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                    <h3>Menu1</h3>
                    <button id="back-step" class="btn btn-basic">Back</button>
                </div>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My JavaScript looks like:

```js
$('#back-step').click(function(){
   $('link1').trigger("click");
});

$(".nav-pills a").click(function(){
    if ($('#first').hasClass('active')){
        $('#first').addClass('test').removeClass('active');            
    }
    $(this).tab('show');
});
```

Comment: Have you tried keeping control of what the tab indexs are?  If you know the index you can navigate back and forth.  It looks like you're trying to initial a click event on a link from a button click to activate your classes.  Use the button as a click event and change the index of the nav pill.  And have an event on the nav pill for selected index changed. The selected index change will trigger you class activation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there's a typo in your JavaScript. You're not targeting the `#link1` id. Try `$('#link1').trigger("click");` (note the hash).

Comment: Another note, the original code you (@Muhammad) posted had mis-matched divs.